# having vertical scroll but no horizontal scroll on fixed table when scrolling to left or right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

I have a html fixed design which has a center aligned table which provides huge data which is scrollable vertically and horizontally.
For the vertical scroll I have cloned the table headers and placed them in a new fixed table above the report table (with the help of jquery clone() and append() functions and CSS fixed position),in this fashion when a user scrolls the report vertically then he will still be able to see the column headers.
Now the issue is that when he scrolls to the right the fixed table scrolls also so the headers are not aligned with the columns,how can I make the new fixed table in such a fashion that the horizontal scroll does not make the fixed table also scroll to the right.
The fixed table has it's parent as the browser window.
I have got a jsfiddle sample going but I cannot get the headers to show when therre is a scroll in this sample ,in my website it shows up when there a vertical scroll 
    http://jsfiddle.net/wnxJ4/8/

```
var tableOffset = $("#table1").offset().top - 10;
var $header = $("#table1 ").clone();
var $fixedtablehead = $("#fixedtablehead").append($header);

$(window).bind("scroll", function() {
    var offset = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (offset >= tableOffset && $fixedtablehead.is(":hidden")) {
        $fixedtablehead.show().css({width: $('#table1').width()});
    }
    else if (offset < tableOffset) {
        $fixedtablehead.hide();
    }
});
```

I am trying to implement the below code for horizontal scroll but I am not able to figure it out properly

```
var position = $(window).scrollLeft();
var lef=$('#fixedtablehead').offset().left;
   alert(lef); 
   alert(lef-position);
   $('#fixedtablehead').css('left',lef-position-position);
```

Comment: @Pilot -> overflow-x:scroll does not work on the fixed table for horizontal scrolling

Comment: Can you get a jsFiddle.net going with that so we can "fiddle" with it? We might think we know what you mean, but we're not sure, given the amount of info you gave us. Just paste your existing code into it and save

Comment: @FernandoSilva  have edited to provide an example

Comment: You missed a `t` in  `$('#fixedtablehead').css('left',left-position-position);`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to put the table and the header inside a div, that div inside another div with a scrollbar and that div with a fixed position, the header should be positioned absolutely on the top, then when you scroll, you scroll the whole div (table+header) and the header moves too

the layout:

```
<div> <-fixed
  <div> <-scrollable
    <table> <-header
    <table> <-content
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bba5g/

EDIT: you should have the content table inside a div with vertical scroll only so you can scroll the content

Answer (score 0):

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZeNz0r/4sMeD/) Look at it here.**

Maybe this type of structure might help out.

HTML:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
    <div class='header'>
        <table class='table'>
            <tr>
                <th>Header1</th>
                <th>Header2</th>
                <th>Header3</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="scrollable">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>TD1</td>
                <td>TD2</td>
                <td>TD3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>TD1</td>
                <td>TD2</td>
                <td>TD3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>TD1</td>
                <td>TD2</td>
                <td>TD3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>TD1</td>
                <td>TD2</td>
                <td>TD3</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.scrollable {
    overflow: scroll;
    height:50px;
    background:#ccc;
}
```

I'm still not sure if this is what you were looking for, but drop a comment if this doesn't help.

Also careful with naming variables, you're using the variable `offset` and that is also the name of a jQuery method. Although usage may differ to call one or the other, but it's always best to avoid same names for different things.

Comment: You can add width to the `.scrollable` class and even use `overflow:auto` so that it only scrolls when the content exceeds the div's size.